# LD_PRELOAD fails on specific folder

Tags: linux, ld-preload

On Ubuntu 16.04 system, been trying to use ld_preload with custom compiled libpcap.so and run tcpdump.

compiling libpcap (1.8.0)

```
./configure --prefix=`pwd`/inst
make install
```

then when using this command, tcpdump uses the custom libpcap

```
LD_PRELOAD=/home/user/tcpdump/inst/libpcap.so.1.8.0 /usr/sbin/tcpdump --version
```

output is:

```
tcpdump version 4.7.4
libpcap version 1.8.0
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

but then, when I move libpcap to a different folder, like /usr/local/lib
it doesn't work anymore.

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1.8.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored
```

as far as I can tell it's some sort of permissions problem. But I chown'ed and chmod'ed everything I could think of.
What am I missing?

That should give you an idea on what might be wrong.

Edit:
The problem seems specific to certain directories and tcpdump itself.
strace output when LD_PRELOAD`ing on /bin/true

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1.8.0 strace -fF  /bin/true 2>&1 | grep libp
open("/usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1.8.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

Here is the strace output on tcpdump

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1.8.0 strace -fF  /usr/sbin/tcpdump 2>&1 | grep libp
open("/usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1.8.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
writev(2, [{"ERROR: ld.so: object '", 22}, {"/usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1.8.0", 31}, {"' from ", 7}, {"LD_PRELOAD", 10}, {" cannot be preloaded (", 22}, {"cannot open shared object file", 30}, {"): ignored.\n", 12}], 7ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1.8.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.so.0.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

both commands were run as sudo

Comment: Is that a typo? `/usr/local/libpcap.so.1.8.0` vs `/usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1.8.0`? Note the `/lib/` part?

Comment: Yes, but the typo was in the post. Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like a problem finding the file (perms or incorrect path). I see that you mention you have moved the file to /usr/local/lib but I see the error message as /usr/local/libpcap.so.1.8.0. Perhaps a typo?

If not, please run

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1.8.0 strace -fF -e open /bin/true 2>&1 | grep libp
```

Another thing to confirm is that /usr/local/lib is in standard path for your linker (if you don't want to use LD_PRELOAD that is):

```
ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'
```

Comment: Yes it was a typo, but in the post itself :) , Anyway, the file is in the correct location ie. /usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1.8.0. Using strace I get an 'access denied' error as the result of the 'open' call to open the .so file. The file has the correct owner (which is root) and I've played with all possible permissions. What's weird is I still don't get  why it works on a different folder but not under /usr/local/lib.

Comment: Do you have selinux enabled? Can you paste output of strace please?

Comment: selinux is not enabled. Added strace output to question.

Comment: tcpdump might be dropping  privileges to a different user. Can everyone read the file? chmod a+r path

Comment: Yes. I've set permission on it, with no change.  Also tcpdump only drops privileges if using -Z option.